# How to find operator norm $T(\bar{x}) = (3x_1 + 2x_2,x_3-4x_4,3x_5 + 2x_6, ...)$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

$$T(\bar{x}) = (3x_1 + 2x_2,x_3-4x_4,3x_5 + 2x_6, ...)$$
Is an operator from $l_2$ to $l_2$. I have tried to find upperbounds and lowerbounds for the supremum but I don't end up with anything I can work with. Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the general formula for the terms of $T(\bar{x})$?

Comment: It alternates between 3,2 and 1,4 for each term

Comment: All you need is definition of norm and C-S inequality. The answer is $\sqrt {17}$ and the norm is attained at the vector $\frac  1{\sqrt {17}} (e_3-4e_4)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**: You can use the Cauchy-Schawrz Inequality to show that $$(3a+2b)^2 = \langle(3,2),(a,b)\rangle^2 \le \|(3,2)\|^2\|(a,b)\|^2 = 13(a^2+b^2)$$ and similarly, $$(a-4b)^2 = \langle(1,-4),(a,b)\rangle^2 \le \|(1,-4)\|^2\|(a,b)\|^2 = 17(a^2+b^2).$$ Using these facts, try to show that $$\|T(\bar{x})\|_{\ell_2}^2 \le C\|\bar{x}\|_{\ell_2}^2,$$ i.e. $$\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}(3x_{4k+1}+2x_{4k+2})^2 + \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}(x_{4k+3}-4x_{4k+4})^2 \le C\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}x_n^2.$$ This will establish that $\|T\| \le \sqrt{C}$. Then, all you need to show is that there is some non-zero sequence $\bar{x}$ such that $\|T(\bar{x})\|_{\ell_2} = C\|\bar{x}\|_{\ell_2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the inequality
$$
(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2 \le 2(a^2 + b^2)
$$
for each of the entries of in the sum defining $\|T(x)\|_{l^2}$.